# A question about mysql joins

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a website, and I'm implementing a friend system. People can become friends and that will unlock some stuff which is not important. It is coded in PHP with MySQL as database.

Lets say this is my account table

```
id | name  | picture
0  | Jorik | Cat.jpg
1  | Joost | Fish.jpg
2  | Henk  | Ferret.png
```

This is the friend table(Is this a good way to do this?)

```
id | user id | friend id | invite date | accepted
0  | 0       | 1         | 123         | 0
1  | 2       | 0         | 456         | 1
2  | 1       | 2         | 123         | 1
```

The way I check if they are friends is as following (Could be an error in it, but you get the idea).

$fid = friend id, $uid = user id.

```
 WHERE ( (`userid` = '{$uid}' && `friendid` = '{fid}' ) || (`friendid` = '{$uid}' && `userid` = '{$fid}' ))
```

First of all, is this an efficient way of doing this or is there a better way?

If I wanted to get the list of friends a user has I can run this query

```
WHERE (`userid` = '{$uid}' || `friendid` = '{$uid}')
```

now if I would run this query for the user 0, it would return

```
id | user id | friend id | invite date | accepted
0  | 0       | 1         | 123         | 0
1  | 2       | 0         | 456         | 1
```

I have worked with MySQL joins before but I can't figure out how to return something like the following result

```
id | friend id | invite date | accepted | Name  | Picture 
0  | 1         | 123         | 0        | Joost | Fish.jpg
1  | 2         | 456         | 1        | Jorik | Ferret.png
```

It would have to check if it should join the friend id or the user id with id from the account table. (The invited person is the friend id, the one who invited him will get the user id.)

I hope I gave enough information.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance,

Jorik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My $0.02:

1) Normalize your data: get rid of the either 'userid' or 'id'. You only need one unique column for accounts.

2) Make a table for 'friends' like so:

( approximately )
create table Friends( UserId int unsigned, FriendUserId int unsigned, index( UserId, FriendUserId ));

Then add a row for each 'friend' where 'FriendUserId' is the account id (see #1) for each person.

3) Make a table for 'invites' like so:
(appx)
create table Invites ( UserId int unsigned, FriendId int unsigned, InviteDate datetime default timestamp, Accepted tinyint(1) default 0,  primary key( UserId, FriendId ));

Add a row for each invite and update if/when its accepted.

Now to get a persons friends:

select * from Accounts a join Friends f on a.UserId = f.UserId where a.UserId = ;

to get Invites:

select * from Accounts a join Invites i on a.UserId = i.UserId

And so on...

.. but more than anything.. avoid duplicating data ..

Comment: This would mean I have to add 2 rows for each friendship, if I read it correct. Isn't my way more easy, just gotta get the join good

Comment: Two rows? Why? The join will give the same results whether its call for 'friend1' or 'friend2' if they are 'friends'. Normalizing the data will make it easier to maintain also (and faster to query). This is huge when the data starts to get big.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, something like this may work:

```
SELECT a.user_id as orig_user_id, f.*, ab.*
FROM account a 
JOIN friends f 
ON f.user_id=a.id 
JOIN account ab 
ON f.friend_id=ab.user_id 
WHERE a.id={$uid}
```

I haven't tested this sql, but you get the picture.  Basically, select the row for the user whose friends you are trying to locate, then join their friends rows, and then join the user account rows for their friends.  You may need to alias some column names to make things clear in your code.  You will have duplicates because you are double joining the account table.

Comment: Hmm that might work, but isn't there a way to do it like: if `friendid` = {$uid} then accountid = userid else accountid = `friendid` and now join the account table with accountid. I just have no idea how to do this in MySQL and if it is efficient.

Comment: You might be able to use conditionals, but that could really make the query slow.  What you are describing are the conditions in the join.  The join says, if there are friends rows for this user id join them and their respective account rows.  If your indexes are setup properly, this is the optimal solution for your layout.  Just make sure that you have keys on those rows, and constraints/FK's if you are using InnoDB.  I would tend to agree with jyeargers solution for your table layout, that would be the most efficient way to deal with the data.

Comment: oke I didn't get awnser from him yet, but does this mean I have to add 2 rows for each friendship? Every friendship also has some options (shared, accepted, date) and the ID is also used for logging, how would I handle this data?

Comment: You would have one row per friend per user.  So if user a had user b as a friend there would be one row.  However, there would be a second row that says user b has a friend user a.  This may seem like duplicate data, but it isn't.  Each user should have their own discrete friends list, where they are the primary user and they have a set of friends.  A setup like this will make your life so much easier.  The number of rows is not really a big deal, the space of storing two ints is nominal compared to the time cost of more complex queries.